# SQL row in one table not in another multiple fields

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am modelling an on-line purchasing and rating service and have two tables:

```
Bought (UserID, ItemID)

Rating (UserID, ItemID, Rating)
```

I want to return those who are in the first table but not in the second one, i.e. those who have bought and item but not rated it.

so far ive got:

```
SELECT 
user,
item 
FROM Buys 
where item NOT IN (SELECT Item FROM Rates);
```

But that will only return users who have bought items which have no ratings at all. As soon as somebody else rates the item it is no longer returned.

How do you specify:

```
SELECT 
user,
item 
FROM Buys 
where item **& user** NOT IN (SELECT Item **& User** FROM Rates);
```

Comment: Please provide sample output.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Bought B
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
   SELECT *
   FROM Rating R
   WHERE B.UserID = R.UserID AND B.ItemID = R.ItemID
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter `UserID` instead of `ItemID`. Also you don't need to filter both `UserID` and `ItemID` to find the user's who didn't rate any product

```
SELECT user,item 
FROM Buys B 
where not exists
(
SELECT 1 
FROM Rates R 
where B.UserID =R.UserID 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

For sql-server use [EXCEPT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(EXCEPT_TSQL);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1);k(MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT);k(DevLang-TSQL)&rd=true)

```
SELECT 
  user, item 
FROM 
  Buys
EXCEPT
SELECT 
  user, item 
FROM 
  Rates
```

For mysql use [MINUS](http://www.bitbybit.dk/carsten/blog/?p=71)

```
SELECT 
  user, item 
FROM 
  Buys
MINUS
SELECT 
  user, item 
FROM 
  Rates
```